# Standardize a Quadratic Form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

standardize Quadratic Form

$$8x_1x_4+2x_3x_4+2x_2x_3+8x_2x_4$$

how to do?

what's the simplest method.

How to choose the first `linear replacement`,

matrix or do by completing the square.

I've tried several times, but failed.

Comment: comment deleted

Comment: @bluesh34 what do you mean?

Comment: I put a comment but then found the answer so I deleted it. It wasn't me who gave the -1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the simplest solution method, but with three or four variables, it is usually easy to diagonalise a quadratic form by hand with *blockwise* Gaussian elimination and *blockwise* eigen-decomposition. We have
\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{1&0&-4&0\\ 0&1&-4&-1\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1}
\pmatrix{0&0&0&4\\ 0&0&1&4\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 4&4&1&0}
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ -4&-4&1&0\\ 0&-1&0&1}
&=\pmatrix{0&-4&0&0\\ -4&-8&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&1&0},\\
\pmatrix{1&\tfrac{-1}2&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 0&0&\tfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
\pmatrix{0&-4&0&0\\ -4&-8&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&1&0}
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\ \tfrac{-1}2&1&0&0\\ 0&0&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\tfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 0&0&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
&=\pmatrix{2&0&0&0\\ 0&-8&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&-1},
\end{align*}
where blockwise Gaussian elimination is used on the first and second lines, and eigen-decomposition is performed on the bottom right $2\times 2$ subblock on the second line. Therefore, if
\begin{align*}
x
=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ -4&-4&1&0\\ 0&-1&0&1}
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\ \tfrac{-1}2&1&0&0\\ 0&0&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\tfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 0&0&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}y,
\end{align*}
then
$$
x^\top\pmatrix{0&0&0&4\\ 0&0&1&4\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 4&4&1&0}x
\ =\ y^\top\pmatrix{2&0&0&0\\ 0&-8&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&-1}y
\ =\ 2y_1^2-8y_2^2+y_3^2-y_4^2.
$$
To solve the problem more systematically, you may perform an orthogonal diagonalisation on the matrix representation of the quadratic form. However, this involves finding the eignvalues of a $3\times3$ or $4\times4$ matrix, which is not easy (and unnecessary) if you do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method with computer:

$$8x_1x_4+2x_3x_4+2x_2x_3+8x_2x_4\\=\frac{{{\left( 5 {x_4}+{x_3}+{x_2}\right) }^{2}}}{2}-\frac{{{\left( 3 {x_4}+{x_3}-{x_2}\right) }^{2}}}{2}-2 {{\left( 2 {x_4}-{x_1}\right) }^{2}}+2 {{x}_{1}^{2}}$$
Formula obtained with  CAS Maxima.  My program work with any quadratic form.